# Pick shortest route with simpleXML

Tags: simplexml

First post so bear with me.

I have hacked together an module for Oscommerce that figures the delivery cost for a pizza delivery.

I used the google distance matrix and got it working only to discover that it picks the fastest route and not the shortest. and there was no option to tell it to pick the shortest.

Oh well.. I poked arround and found that i could use the direction api instead

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Svendborgvej%20323,%205260%20Odense%20S,%20Denmark&destination=Albanivej%2027,%205792%20%C3%85rslev&alternatives=true

now i have 2 routes in that XML and i need

1. pick the shortest one
2. extract the distance from it

my code so far: http://pastebin.com/t3KY5Qzn

i'm not a very good programmer and a bit stuck here... anyone that could help me out?

i used an online xml viewer to get a more human readable format and i can see the 2 blocks with 1 route in it and also the total distance in each..

Comment: hmm.. trying myself

// work out DISTANCE UNITS
      $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=' . MODULE_SHIPPING_DISTANCE_ORIGIN . '&destinations=' . $destination . '&units=' . MODULE_SHIPPING_DISTANCE_UNITS;
      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $data = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);
      $geocode = simplexml_load_string($data, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
      
      $actual_distance = $geocode->row->element->distance->value;      
      $miles = $actual_distance/1609.34;
      $km = $actual_distance/1000;

Comment: So i could change 

$actual_distance = $geocode->row->element->distance->value;

to

$actual_distance = $geocode->route->leg->distance->value;

but that will only get me one  distance... no gurantee that the first one will be the shortest or that it will every time

Comment: just tested it... i only get the first one...

http://xn--pizzalg-v1a.dk/distance.php

Comment: Got it a bit further.... basicly just experimenting and using google 

<?php

  $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Svendborgvej%20323,%205260%20Odense%20S,%20Denmark&destination=Albanivej%2027,%205792%20%C3%85rslev&alternatives=true';
      $ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $data = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);
      
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

$result = $xml->xpath('/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/distance/value');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo 'Distance: ',$node/1000,"\n","<br>";
}

Comment: the above gives me each of the 2 routes total distance on a line, but now how do i pick the lowest value of the 2 and put that in a new string?

Comment: hate to be an jerk but i can answer this one myself

Answer (score 0):

its a simple as: echo min($result)

from there its simple to mod my module so it picks the shortest route of those google might give